# Can a std::function typedef be used to help define a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Let's say a I have a `typedef` for a specific `std::function` such as:

```
typedef std::function<int(int a, int b, int c)> func_type;
```

Can I reuse that typedef when defining a lambda that implements it?

For example, in the example below, the function `foo` accepts a `func_type`, but the call-site for `foo` needs to replicate the signature:

```
void foo(func_type f) {
  // ...
}

int main() {
  foo([](int a, int b, int c){ return a + b + c; });
}
```

Can I somehow re-use the `func_type` typedef when declaring the lambda, so I don't have to repeat the argument list (and so changes to the `func_type` typedef will be transparent for lambda bodies that work with the new definition).

Something like `[](??? func_type ???){ return a + b + c; }`.

Comment: Basically typedef for a function arguments list? I don't think that there is such a thing, except for packing it in macro.

Comment: @VTT - yeah, more or less - I assume the capture list should still be specified, and certainly the body... It's kind of the same question as re-using a function (not `std::function`, I mean something like `typedef int (func_type)(int, int, int)`) as part of the function _definition_. As far as I know, you can't in that case (you can for the _declaration_, however).

Comment: You could make something like `[](auto... T) -> Match<func_type, decltype(T)... {}` but that's probably just making things more complicated.... ? :-)

Comment: how do you intend to name the arguments you are using within your lambda without naming them in the signature?  Do you want to extract those names from the `std::function`?  If so, no, that is not possible, those names have no impact on the type of the `std::function`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable names in `std::function<int(int a, int b, int c)>` are not part of the type -- they are basically comments.  There is no way to extract them at any other point.

So if you hope to get `a`, `b` and `c` you are out of luck.

One simple thing you can do is use `auto`:

```
foo( [](auto...args) { return args+...+0; } );
```

which is close to what you want.  If you have 3 arguments you can do:

```
foo( [](auto a, auto b, auto c) { return a+b+c; } );
```

But the return type doesn't match, other than because `std::function` does the conversion for you.

You can extract the types of `a` `b` and `c` and make the lambda work differently, but not with the return type.  Not unless you do something insane like:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t{ contexpr tag_t(){} using type=T; };
template<class T>
constexprt tag_t<T> tag{};
template<class Tag>
using type_t = typename Tag::type;

template<class F>
struct deducer {
  F f;
  template<class R, class...Args>
  operator std::function<R(Args...)>() const {
    return f( tag<R>, tag<Args>... );
  }
};

template<class F>
deducer<F> make_deducer( F f ){ return {std::move(f)}; }

int main() {
  foo(make_deducer([](auto R, auto...Args){
    return []( type_t<decltype(Args)>... args )->type_t<decltype(R)> {
      return 0+...args;
    });
  }));
}
```

I would advise against this.  But I deduced the argument types and return type of the lambda from what `std::function` I was passed to.

What we do here is we create a deducer type, that when converted to a `std::function` passes the arguments and return type expected to a lambda it stores.  That lambda then generates a custom lambda for those exact arguments.

This is neither brief, simple nor sane.

Comment: Thanks Yakk. I think the `auto` solutions aren't available to me since I'm using C++11 and I think generic lamda's aren't available until C++14, right? Thanks for the notes about the more extreme solutions, but as you suggest, I'll avoid them. It was just an attempt at a bit of DRY. An actual example would be a "predicate" lambda whose arguments change from time to time, but for the "always true" version of the predicate the body doesn't refer to them at all - it is always `return true;` (perhaps there are other better ways to solve that specific case too).

Comment: @BeeOnRope Oh, that is easy: `struct always_true_t { template<class...Ts> bool operator()(Ts&&)const{return true;} constexpr always_true_t() {} }; constexpr always_true_t always_true{};` -- then just use `always_true`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have a `std::function` and what you want to do is defer the selection of the type arguments to `std::function`, you can just have a generic lambda:

```
foo([](auto... xs) { return (... + xs); });
```

Since it's `std::function`'s call operator that drives how the lambda is called, this'll do the right thing. Of course, this requires C++14 (and the fold-expression I used above requires C++17, but that's not as important). You may or may not want to use `auto&&`, depending on what the types actually are.

For C++11, you can't easily do such a thing with a lambda. You'd need to fix the arity and manually list all the types. This isn't practical. You could fallback to using a normal function object, with a call operator template, but then you lose the advantages of a lambda.

Comment: And what if the return expression would not just be the the addition of all its elements, but something like (a+2*b)/c ?

Comment: @Christophe So... write that? `[](auto a, auto b, auto c){ return (a + 2*b)/c; }`?

Comment: ok, nice, the auto arguments provide a little more flexibility. But can we really call this a reuse of the func_type signature asked by OP ?  And the return type of the lambda in absence of explicit specification, isn't it defined by type returned rather than the signature of func_type ?

Answer (score 0):

A [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is

> is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper. Instances of
>   std::function can store, copy, and invoke any Callable target --
>   functions, **lambda expressions**, bind expressions, or other function
>   objects, as well as pointers to member functions and pointers to data
>   members.  
> -- source cppreference.com

So yes, this approach is perfectly valid !

However the signature of the typedef can't be taken over to short-circuit the lambda definition.

**Remark:**  The typedef is about the return type and the parameter types but not the parameter names,  so if short-circuiting the parameter list would be legal, the body of the lambda would not know which parameters to use:

```
int main() {
  foo([](int d, int e, int f){ return d + e + f; });
}
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I know a lambda can be used as a callable that is convertable to a `std::function`. The question is if I can do that without duplicating in the source the arguments and return type of the lambda, i.e., use `func_type` in the declaration of the lambda such that if the `typedef` changes the lambda changes as well (including possibly causing a compile error if the new typedef is incompatible with the body of the lambda). Suggestions welcome as to the question text to make this clear.

Comment: @BeeOnRope oops, sorry,  if I misunderstood.  i've edited the answer accordingly